# How to set Cron Job on Vultr (Ubuntu Lemp)

Tags: ubuntu

i have my website online using lemp and i have written my command to execute but i do not know how to set it on Ubuntu Lemp.

Normally it is easy on shared hosting using Cpanel. Please how do i schedule cron job for everyday by 8pm.

Comment: There is no product called "Ubuntu Lemp", but if you Google LEMP you can find pages with instructions for setting up Nginx, MySQL, and PHP. If, on the other hand, you're asking about cron, search for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Vultr has the ability to deploy applications through the 1 click apps

- https://www.vultr.com/apps/lemp
- https://www.vultr.com/features/one-click-apps/

As for setting up a cron. You will want to make sure that you have the cron package installed on the instance.

The cron entry to run a task everyday at 8pm would be
`0 8 * * *`

You can find a more detailed guide here:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux